# Get variables from Jinja2 template

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I need to extract variable names (with JSON) from this Jinja2 template with functions:

```
{{ variable }}
{{ some.variable.type.json }}
{{ _("Hello") }}
<p>Some HTML file</p>
```

I need to get output something like this:

```
{'some': {'variable': {'type': {'json': <scalar>}}}, 'variable': <scalar>}
```

Or this:

```
["some.variable.type.json", "variable"]
```

I tried Environment from jinja2:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, meta

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(""))
template_source = env.loader.get_source(env, "test.html")[0]
parsed_content = env.parse(template_source)
variables = meta.find_undeclared_variables(parsed_content)
print(variables)
```

But it returns function names in output and don't return all JSON name:

```
{'some', 'variable'}
```

I tried jinja2schema too:

```
import jinja2schema

with open("test.html", mode="r") as f:
    template = str("".join(f.readlines()))
    variables = jinja2schema.infer(template)

    print(variables)
```

It returns what I want without functions, but when in HTML is some Jinja2 function, then I got Exception:

```
jinja2schema.exceptions.InvalidExpression: line 3: "_" call is not supported
```

Is there any way to get full variables from Jinja2 template withou function names?
Thanks for help

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question, are you needing just JSON output formatted using a Jinja2 template? If that is the case, why are you needing to use Jinja2 to format the data rather than creating a dictionary and the JSON library?

Comment: I need to extract full variable reference (like something.hello.value.suffix) from Jinja2 template, but I don't want to get only first word of this JSON variable

Comment: Is it because you need to get the environment variable from the Jinja2 environment and you don't know where else to reference it? My confusion is that Jinja2 should be used for formatting information as opposed to accessing information.

Comment: Yes, I need to dynamically get variables what I must give to Jinja2 template.

Comment: Your solution (calling `variables = meta.find_undeclared_variables(parsed_content)`) is returning the correct information. From the perspective of Jinja, `some` and `variable` are the only two undefined variables. `some.variable.type.json` is trying to dereference attributes of `some`, which may or may not work after `some` is defined with some value.

Comment: Ok and is there any solution, how can i get the last attribute of variable? Or all attributes by this method?